# What is the current state-of-the-art of function-private functional encryption?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, functional-encryption

Are there any known constructions of functional encryption with function-privacy for arbitrary functions (e.g. not just inner-product)? If so, are these constructions currently feasible or for now just theoretical?